# ExpressionEngine + Slider, how do I get it to display correctly?

Tags: count, html

I suppose I could consider my very experienced with ExpressionEngine.. But I've come across a stumper here and I know the answer is probably obvious.

Client has handed me a design to port over to expression engine and implement all the bells and whistles. They have included their slider of choice in the design.

```
   <div class="slider">
     <div class="shell">        
        <div class="slider-caption">
           <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>

           <h2>Epsum factorial <br /> non deposit</h2>

           <div class="actions">
              <a href="#" class="link-more">read more</a>
           </div><!-- /.actions -->   
        </div><!-- /.slider-caption -->        
     </div><!-- /.shell -->
     <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide">
           <img src="{images}/slide-01.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>

        <li class="slide">
           <img src="{images}/slide-02.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>

        <li class="slide">
           <img src="{images}/slide-01.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>

        <li class="slide">
           <img src="{images}/slide-02.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
     </ul><!-- /.slides -->
     <div class="shell">
        <div class="slider-paging"></div><!-- /.slider-paging -->
     </div><!-- /.shell -->
  </div><!-- /.slider -->
```

^I'm sure you've seen the problem already. I cannot simply 'wrap' this section inside a channel tag, it would break the styling. Nor can I simply use two channel tags (unless I'm missing something) to populate both areas and keep them in sync with each other for each slide.

Here was my initial (lazy) attempt:

```
 <div class="slider">
     <div class="shell">        
         {exp:channel:entries channel="home_slider" limit="4" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic="no"}
          <div class="slider-caption">
           <h3>{title}</h3>

           <h2>{home_slider_text}</h2>

           {if home_slider_link !==''}
           <div class="actions">
              <a href="{home_slider_link}" class="link-more">read more</a>
           </div><!-- /.actions -->   
           {/if}
           </div><!-- /.slider-caption -->  
          {/exp:channel:entries}      
     </div><!-- /.shell -->
     <ul class="slides">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="home_slider" limit="4" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic="no"}
        <li class="slide">
           <img src="{home_slider_image}" alt="{title}" />
        </li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
     </ul><!-- /.slides -->
     <div class="shell">
        <div class="slider-paging"></div><!-- /.slider-paging -->
     </div><!-- /.shell -->
  </div><!-- /.slider -->
```

I'm thinking the answer lies in being clever with an {if count} approach, but I'm scratching my head on this.

Any words of advice?

Note: To make this even more frustrating, a long time ago I dealt with a similar problem and fixed it.. But I don't have access (nor even remember the url) to that site.

Edit: Upon further investigation.. It seems that this slider they chose isn't actually transitioning\hiding the slide text- only the slide images themselves. Curious.

Seems the issue isn't with me per se but with their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you do not use separate entry for each slider, but have one entry with 2 custom fields:

- slider caption (text field)
- slide images (Matrix or Grid field)

This way, you will simply loop over Grid/Matrix field while staying in same Channel entry.